# No networking out of Docker bridge

Tags: networking, iptables, docker

The gist of the issue is that if I create and run a docker container (from any image, I tried many) **the container does not have external network access** beyond the default bridge Docker creates; even when using IP addresses (not URLs/names).

I.e.

- `docker run --rm -it busybox ping 8.8.8.8` hangs/fails for not having accessing the network
- `docker run --rm -it busybox ping 172.17.0.1` also fails (note that `172.17.0.1` is `docker0`'s IP on the host and also the gateway set by docker in the container)
- if I create two containers I can ping either one from the other fine (as they are both connected to the docker bridge)

Networking from the host works fine (I can ping out, etc.).  Also of I run `docker run --network host --rm -it busybox ping 8.8.8.8`, it reaches the server and responds in a timely fashion.

It is not a `ping` problem: `traceroute`, `wget` and `apt-get update` also fail.  (They fail with IP addresses and also with URLs; even when DNS servers are OK in `/etc/resolv.conf` on both the host and the in the container.)

N.B:

1. I have two Ubuntu hosts (same version) both running Docker 19.03.6.  On one of them (dev machine) I don't have the issue (it works just fine), on the other one I do.  Which means it is most likely not an OS and/or Docker version issue but some sort of misconfiguration.
2. It is **not** the DNS issue asked in most questions I could find.  In fact, it is not a DNS issue at all.  It presents itself when I use direct IP addresses as well as with URLs.

I use `iptables` on the host.  These are the rules (from `iptables-save`) on the one where it does not work (they are different on the dev machine where networking works fine but I cannot set the same ones here):

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Wed Apr 15 23:14:15 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [14467:1224366]
:INPUT ACCEPT [479:21744]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [249:15752]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [249:15752]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Apr 15 23:14:15 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Wed Apr 15 23:14:15 2020
*filter
:INPUT DROP [4360:696740]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [9497:1567380]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
:f2b-postfix-sasl - [0:0]
:f2b-sshd - [0:0]
:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587,220,993,110,995 -j f2b-postfix-sasl
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 143 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 993 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A f2b-postfix-sasl -j RETURN
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Apr 15 23:14:15 2020
```

I tried to stop `dockerd`, remove the docker-related rules by hand, and restart the daemon.  It recreated the same rules and the problem persists.

I am not a `iptables` wizard, so it may be a near-trivial issue or one unrelated to iptables altogether ;/.

I am not sure what else to add for clarification.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with bridged network on docker 19.03.8 on ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (pc1) and I managed to finally solve it.

I had docker working on the other pc (pc2) that also used ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS but with docker 19.03.5.

I compared IPTABLES - for some reason, during my attempts to fix the problem, I was missing few rules. The rules I use now on pc1 are:

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -N DOCKER
sudo iptables -N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
sudo iptables -N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
sudo iptables -N DOCKER-USER
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

I also removed `sudo rm /etc/docker/daemon.json` (had some conflicts with VPN and I've previously changed bip).
Final step was: `sudo service docker restart`

Result:

```
$ docker run --rm -it busybox ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=54 time=9.479 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=54 time=7.697 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 7.697/8.588/9.479 ms
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jacek Kobus for the help!  I followed the steps but unfortunately they didn't help in my case (nothing seems to have changed).  My setup is similar but not identical to yours: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and Docker 19.03.6 on both machines.  (Docker is deployed from its website not through apt.)  The difference in success maybe due to systemd?.

Comment: Your only option now is to compare both pc's step by step as I did. Also make sure to eliminate external factors, like any VPN networks and/or custom configuration changes.